# X axis not showing all labels for certain dates

Tags: javascript, d3.js

See JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wc34frjd/1/

For certain dates, the first date label on the X axis is not shown.
For example, dates from "2015-02-06" to "2015-02-12" show all labels, but changing the month to 04 results in the first label missing.

```
            var data = [
                        {value: 0, date: "2015-04-06"},
                        {value: 10, date: "2015-04-07"},
                        {value: 0, date: "2015-04-08"},
                        {value: -20, date: "2015-04-09"},
                        {value: 0, date: "2015-04-10"},
                        {value: 30, date: "2015-04-11"},
                        {value: 0, date: "2015-04-12"}
                        ];
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: D3 determines the labels to be shown automatically. Try calling `.nice()` on your scale after setting the domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need specific labels, you should mention them in `.tickValues([...])` method.

```
        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient('bottom')
        .ticks(tickTime, tickSkips)
        .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%a %d'))
        .tickSize(0)
        .tickPadding(10)
        .tickValues([new Date('2015-4-6'), new Date('2015-4-9'), new Date('2015-4-12')]);
```